# Regex match last instance of B where B is behind it, but not before A

Tags: java, regex, pcre

I've been trying to modify the regular expression I built a long time ago to support more complicated input, but haven't been able to get it working. Here is sample input with the current expression that already works, as well as sample input of what I want to support, and haven't been able to get to work.

Regular Expression

```
\{([^{}']*\{[\d]+(?:,[^,}]+)*}.*?)}
```

Working sample input

```
{{0}}
{{0,test}}
{test {0,test}}
{{0,test} test2}
{test {0,test} test2}
```

Input I want to support

```
test {test {0, test} test2 {1} test3 {2}}
test {test {0, test} test2 {1} test3 {2}} {3}
test {test {0, test} test2 {1} test3 {2}} asdf
{test {0, test} test2 {1} test3 {2}}
{test {0, test} test2 {1} test3 {2} test4}
{test {0, test} test2 {1} test3 {2} test4} test5 {3}
```

In the samples I'd like to support, what it should find would be the last instance of `}` where it has `}` behind it, but not `{`.

Valid matches (I want these)

```
test {test {0, test} test2 {1} test3 {2}}            -> test {0, test} test2 {1} test3 {2}
test {test {0, test} test2 {1} test3 {2}} {3}        -> test {0, test} test2 {1} test3 {2}
test {test {0, test} test2 {1} test3 {2}} asdf       -> test {0, test} test2 {1} test3 {2}
{test {0, test} test2 {1} test3 {2}}                 -> test {0, test} test2 {1} test3 {2}
{test {0, test} test2 {1} test3 {2} test4}           -> test {0, test} test2 {1} test3 {2} test4
{test {0, test} test2 {1} test3 {2} test4} test5 {3} -> test {0, test} test2 {1} test3 {2} test4
{test {0, test} test2 {1} test3 {2} test4} test5 {3  -> test {0, test} test2 {1} test3 {2} test4
```

Invalid match (I don't want these in the fixed regex)

```
 {test {0, test} test2 {1} test3 {2} test4} test5 {3} -> test {0, test} test2 {1} test3 {2} test4} test5 {3
```

I've already spent 2 hours modifying it the best I can on https://regex101.com to no avail.

To clarify the tags, the regular expression is for the Java regex dialect, so while it is PCRE, certain boundaries/operators are unsupported.

Comment: Does ist hav to a single regex? Maybe a parser would be maintainable and easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match the opening and closing curly brace and in between use a capturing group where you would match from an opening till closing curly and the non curly content before and after it.

The value is in group 1.

```
{((?:[^{}]*{[^{}]*}[^{}]*)*)}
```

**Explanation**

- `{` Match opening curly
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `[^{}]*` Match 0+ times any char except `{` or `}`
    - `{[^{}]*}` Match from opening `{` till closing `}`
    - `[^{}]*` Match 0+ times any char except `{` or `}`
  - `)*` Close non capture group and repeat 0+ times
- `)` Close group 1
- `}` Match closing curly

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kqVPL5/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/1ZI5lu)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to catch, but here is a working regex:

```
{[^{}]*(({[^{}]+})[^{}]*)+}
```

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/kxYm3U/2).

The curly braces at the beginning and at the end are what interests you.